# Percentages - Find Maximum value.

Tags: linear-programming, algebra-precalculus

3 candidates A,B and C contest an election. A gets at least 40% of all the votes. B gets at least 20% of the number of votes that A gets and cannot get more than 80% of number of votes that c gets. What is the maximum percentage of votes that a can get?

I am looking at a generic way how to solve these questions on finding maximum values of variables where the values are inter-dependent. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to sign your posts: see [Can I use a signature or tagline?](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) from the FAQ.

Comment: @BenMillwood Thanks. Removed the signature.

Answer (score 2):

The technique to be used depends heavily on context.  The problem is a standard *linear programming* problem.  But since you are using the tag "quantitative aptitude," we will first try to solve the problem by reasoning.

The number of votes $A$ gets is largest if (i) $B$ gets exactly $20\%$ of the votes $A$ gets, and (ii) $B$ gets $80\%$ of the votes $C$  gets. Let $z$ be $C$'s vote percentage. Then $B$'s is $(0.8)z$, and $A$'s is $(5)(0.8z)$.

But the vote percentages add up to $100$. This gives the equation $(5)(0.8z)+(0.8z)+z=100$. So $5.8z=100$, and therefore $z=\frac{100}{5.8}$. It follows that $A$ gets the percentage $\frac{400}{5.8}$, a bit under $69\%$ of the vote.

**Another way:** Another approach is **graphical**. We stop using percentages, and use fractions instead. Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ respectively be the *fractions* of the vote obtained by $A$, $B$, and $C$.  We have $x+y+z=1$, and therefore $z=1-x-y$.  So effectively we have a two variable problem.

Now you will need to use paper and ruler, and draw carefully the lines described below. We are told that $x \ge \frac{2}{5}$. **Draw** the line $x=\frac{2}{5}$. We must be to the right of it.

We are told that $y \ge \frac{1}{5}x$.  **Draw** the line $y=\frac{x}{5}$ or equivalently $5y=x$.  We must be above it.

We are told that $y \le \frac{4}{5}z$. So $y \le \frac{4}{5}(1-x-y)$, which simplifies to $\frac{9y}{5} \le \frac{4}{5} -\frac{4}{5}x$.  **Draw** the line $\frac{9y}{5}=\frac{4}{5}-\frac{4x}{5}$, that is, $9y=4-4x$.   We must be below this line.

If you consider the three geometrical constraints, and have drawn the diagram carefully, you will see that we must be in a certain triangle. And it is obvious that $x$ is biggest at the rightmost corner of that triangle, which is where the lines $5y=x$ and $9y=4-4x$ meet. Solve to find $x$.

**Remark:** In the real world, problems with a similar structure occur, often with hundreds (or more) variables and hundreds (or more) linear constraints. There are efficient procedures, such as the *simplex method*, for solving such problems, of course by computer. The field is called *Linear Programming*. It is of great practical importance.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to interpret the information you are given into equations.  Let $a,b,c$ be the percentages gathered by $A, B, C$.  The first sentence tells you $a+b+c=100$.  The second says $a \ge 40$.  The third says $b \ge 0.2a$ and also that $b \le 0.8c$.

In this case, if we want to maximize the number of votes $a$ gets, we should minimize the number $b$ and $c$ get.  So let $b=0.2a$, which is the minimum for $b$.  Then $c \ge 1.25b = 0.25a$ and to minimize that, we have equality as well.  Now plug those into the first equation, getting $a + 0.2a + 0.25a=100$ or $a=\frac {100}{1.45}$.  It is a bit surprising this didn't come out cleanly.  Then you can verify that in fact $a \ge 40$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking on the question where the variables are inter-dependent, the BEST way to set up a proper solution is to assign each task with a variable and consider the relations between them. For instance, if we let the percentage of candidate A is x percent, analogously, we also assign y and z for candidate B and C respectively. The obvious implication would be $x+y+z=100$ and other restrictions are also taken into account. Hope this gives you some hint on solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let total number of votes = 100x
so A will get at least = 40% of 100x = 40x 
means number of votes that A will get >= 40x
Let C get a% of total votes = ax
Number of votes that B gets = at least 20% of A (that is 8x) and at max 80% of C
To maximize %tage of votes obtained by A we need to minimize B and C. 
When A = 40x , B = 8x and C = 10x
Thus in 58x , A can get at max 40x
So maximum possible votes that A can get, = 40x/58x 100 = 68.96%